# Boxes of type A and B: Probabilities

Tags: probability, probability-theory, density-function

The weight of boxes of type A is uniformly distributed on $[20,40]$.

As for boxes of type B, the weight $X$ gets values between $40$ and $60$ kilos and the density in that interval is $f_X=c\cdot x$, ($40<x<60$).

A company gets boxes of type A with possibility $60\%$ and of type B with possibility $40\%$.

1. Determine the constant $c$.
2. Under which weight $b_1$, a random box has possibility $20\%$ to weight less than $b_1$ ?
3. Which is the mean value of the weight of a random box?
4. If we load $100$ random boxes into a container, which is the possibility that the total weight of the loaded boxes is less than $39000$ kg ?

$$$$

I have done the following:

1. We have that $$\int_{40}^{60}f_X\, dx=P(X\in [40,60])=40\% \Rightarrow c=0.0004$$ Is that correct?
2. We are looking for $b_1$ such that $P(X<b_1)=20\%$, aren't we? Do we get that value as follows? \begin{align*}&P(X<b_1)=\int_{40}^{b_1}f_X\, dx \Rightarrow 0.2=\int_{40}^{b_1}0.0004x \Rightarrow 0.2=\left [0.0002x^2\right ]_{40}^{b_1} \\ & \Rightarrow 1000=\left [x^2\right ]_{40}^{b_1} \Rightarrow 1000=b_1^2-1600 \Rightarrow b_1^2=2600 \Rightarrow b_1=10\sqrt{26}\end{align*}

Could you give me also a hint for the last two questions?

Comment: I don't understand your answer for the first part.  For box $B$, the probability that its weight falls between $40$ and $60$ is $1$, by definition.  At no point in your calculation do you appear to use the fact that the distribution of weights is $cx$.

Comment: Iused the fact that "A company gets boxes of type A with possibility $60\%$ and of type B with possibility $40\%$. " Is that wrong? Should the integral of the density be equal to $1$ instead? @lulu

Comment: The distribution of the box type has nothing to do with it.  For this problem, you are only looking at boxes of type $B$.

Comment: Nor do I understand your second computation.  For that one,  you appear to be imagining that you always get a box of type $B$, but of course that is not true.

Comment: So at the first question it should be: $$\int_{40}^{60}f_X\, dx=1 \Rightarrow c[x^2]_{40}^{60}=1 \Rightarrow 1000c=1\Rightarrow 0.0001$$ or not? @lulu

Comment: Well, almost.  $\frac 1{1000}=.001$

Comment: Oh yes!! So, as for the second question, do we have to take cases if $b_1$ is between 20 and 40 or between 40 and 60? If yes,would it be as follows $$P(X<b_1)=\int_{20}^{b_1}f_X\, dx+\int_{b_1}^{60}f_X\, dx$$ Or should we calculate that seperately each case? @lulu

Comment: Well, $f_X$ only applies to type $B$ boxes, and for this question you need to consider the probability that you get $A$ or $B$. Go slowly, don't jump at answers.  Try a particular value.  Say $b_1=40$.  What's the probability that a random box weighs less than $40$?  (Hint:  that one doesn't require any computation).  Now try $b_1=30$.  If you can do that, you should be able to solve the problem.

Comment: Since for a box A we have uniformly distribution we have that $P(x<X<x+d)=\frac{d}{b-a}$,right? @lulu

Comment: Yes, trusting that $b=40, a=20$ and $20≤x$ and $x+d≤40$.

Comment: Do we have that $$P(X<b_1)=P(X_A<b_1)+P(X_B<b_1)$$ ? @lulu

Comment: No.  You are going too fast here, it's causing you to make lots of careless errors.  If, say, $b_1=100$ then your formula gives a probability of $2$.

Comment: Ahh ok.... Could you give me a hint what we should do here instead? @lulu

Comment: I told you.  You have to consider the probabilities of getting box $A$ or $B$.  Then, try  particular values.  Don't just jump into the general computation.

Comment: I haven't really understood what I have to do. Could you explain that further to me? @lulu

Comment: I think you need to review the basics.  For this problem, I'll just answer the first question I suggested you do for warm up "what's the probability that a random box weighs $≤40$."  For that, just remark that this is the same as requiring that it be of type $A$, since all Type $A$ boxes weigh $≤40$ and no type $B$ box does (note that the probability of a $B$ box weighing exactly $40$ is $0$ so we can neglect that possibility).  Thus the probability that the random box weighs  $≤40$ is the same as the probability that it has type $A$, so the answer is $.6$

Comment: Since we are looking for the possibility $P(X<b_1)$ and we have just an upperbound, that means that the weights are from $0$ to $b_1$. Since the fact that a box weights between 20 and $40$ has the probability $0.6$, that means that $b_1$ must be less than $40$ or not? @lulu

Comment: Yes, the calculation I wrote shows that the answer to the question, $b_1$ must be less than $40$.  My next suggestion was to try $b_1=30$.  Of course, guessing probably won't solve the problem, but that's not the point.  The point is that working a clear numerical example should give you clarity.  When you do the calculation abstractly, you can check that it matches the result you got numerically.